# ng-file-upload not uploading in Ionics

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, ionic-framework, ng-file-upload

I am using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) library for my Ionic mobile application and Im having challenges in implementing this library. I also used Codeigniter for my REST API. My upload request should have fields(some data) and the images. here is my code so far:

```
$scope.doSubmitAttachment = function(){
    console.log('@@@@@doSubmitAttachement- Process Request--' + $scope.images);
    $scope.upload($scope.images);
    };



$scope.upload = function (file) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'http://192.168.8.247:130/api/upload',
        fields: {'username': 'juan'},
        file: file
    }).progress(function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name);
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + data);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('error status: ' + status);
    })
};
```

This is already connected to a button, but everytime I press the button, nothing happens, In the log file i get error 0.

```
09-01 11:56:07.726  11315-11315/com.ionicframework.myapp I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "@@@@@doSubmitAttachement- Process Request--file:///data/data/com.ionicframework.myapp/cache/maxresdefault1914240190.jpg", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)

09-01 11:58:14.906  11315-11315/com.ionicframework.myapp I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "error status: 0", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)

09-01 13:16:09.602    1541-1541/com.ionicframework.mase101409 I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "error data: null", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)

09-01 13:16:09.602    1541-1541/com.ionicframework.mase101409 I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "error config: [object Object]", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)

09-01 13:16:09.606    1541-1541/com.ionicframework.mase101409 I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "error headers: function (name) {
if (!headersObj) headersObj =  parseHeaders(headers);
if (name) {
var value = headersObj[lowercase(name)];
if (value === void 0) {
value = null;
}
return value;
}
return headersObj;
}", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)
```

======EDIT 2=======

I now have a response from the server, i inputed the wrong url. But the problem now is I cant parse the reponse in $_FILES in my codeigniter backend. I var_dump it and here is the response:

```
09-01 23:13:59.801    5236-5236/com.ionicframework.mase101409 I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "file uploaded. Response: array(0) {
}
", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)
```

Looking forward for your help,I cant figure out what im missing.

Thanks

Comment: That log alone doesn't say much. Try printing `data` too.

Comment: I printed each response in error function above:

09-01 13:16:09.602    1541-1541/com.ionicframework.mase101409 I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "error data: null", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)


09-01 13:16:09.602    1541-1541/com.ionicframework.mase101409 I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "error config: [object Object]", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)

Comment: @yvesmancera i already added some log files.

Comment: See the network tab of the client to make sure all files are being sent in the request. If that is the case then it would be a server side question so not related to ionic or ng-file-upload. You can find any example of uploading multiple files using simple html form submit for php and make your code like that.

Comment: I just looked into the codes and after serveral hours of trying to know what is wrong.First I tried to create a sample app using ionic and add the sample codes found in ng-file-upload (http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/1m6fn6re/) , I found out that the plugin is working if you run it on browser, so in my mobile code I change it to the the running code in browser and It submit the file perfectly, BUT, so sad it only really supports ONE upload per request, UNLESS your in html5 browser, and in the case of mobile app it is not running under html5.Correct me if im wrong about this :)

Comment: Mobile app should support html5 too. It is mostly for IE8-9 that need flash shim.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/480#issuecomment-114865968) on the repo, you can't use ng-file-upload with Cordova. Instead, you have to use [cordova-plugin-file-transfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) and, if you want, its [ng-cordova adapter](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/).

Comment: No votes or comments on this answer. Really isn't ng-file-upload working with the Ionic and the only option is cordova-plugin-file-transfer??

Comment: Did you manage to fix this in the end using either of the plugins mentioned by Deurco?